# Navigation Stack's Global Planning Algorithm

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**What kind of algorithm is used for global planner?**

I've already read a paper on nav stack, "The Office Marathon".
The paper says that global planner assumes that **A* algorithm** is used.
And it also refer to a paper "**A gradient method for realtime robot control**".

Once I asked a similar question and got the latter method is used as global planner.
http://answers.ros.org/question/37332/an-algorithm-used-for-navigation-stack/

**A* algorithm is used for ... what ?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50849/navigation-stack%27s-global-planning-algorithm/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, the navigation stack's global planner (provided by the [navfn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn) package) uses Dijkstra's algorithm. See http://answers.ros.org/question/28366/why-navfn-is-using-dijkstra/ for discussion on why that is the case and some more info about the A* implementation available in that package.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you. I read source code and confirmed the algorithm.